# Unable to execute chromedriver on a Ubuntu instance (AWS) via Jenkins (The driver is not executable)?

Tags: java, linux, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

The following code references the chromedriver (Not .exe) file:

```
        case "chrome":
            if(SystemUtils.IS_OS_LINUX) {
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", Global_Vars.CHROME_DRIVER_DIRECTORY_UBUNTU_LINUX);
```

When attempting to trigger my tests via Jenkins Iam seeing the following exception message:

```
Message: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver is not executable: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/AutomationFramework/src/main/java/driver/drivers/chromedriver
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:585)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:150)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:141)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:35)
```

Please note; when running tests from Jenkins hosted on a windows machine, the tests run okay (Logic to reference chromedriver.exe).

I'am able to locate the chromedriver file on the AWS instance:
[image]

My chromedriver path:

```
System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/main/java/driver/drivers/chromedriver
```

Comment: You haven't defined what `Global_Vars.CHROME_DRIVER_DIRECTORY_UBUNTU_LINUX` is. Please edit your question and provide an [mcve].

Comment: @JeffC now added.